# Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI in PHP nusoap

Tags: php, xml, soap, nusoap

I'm getting following error response while I subscribe to service. **Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI**

**Response** :

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.0.5.GA (build: CVSTag=Branch_4_0 date=200610162339)/Tomcat-5.5
X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ED9D677679699927EC1C9CBACE00B7BA.server2; Path=/
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 25 Oct 2013 07:17:58 GMT
Connection: close
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/none</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:C8F752B9E879AE5333138268547859511312499</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</wsa:Action>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode/>
            <faultstring>Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI</faultstring>
            <detail/>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my php code. I have used nusoap

```
     require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

    // Load SOAP URL
    $client = new nusoap_client('http://192.168.1.34:1212/services/MYInterfaceTestingMgrService?wsdl','wsdl');
    $client->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';
    $client->useHTTPPersistentConnection(); // Uses http 1.1 instead of 1.0
    $soapaction = 'RemoveAppendantProduct'; // Load SOAP Action

    // soap message
    $request_xml =  <<<SOAPXML
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:bus="http://www.xyz.com/bme/cbsinterface/cbs/businessmgrmsg" 
    xmlns:com="http://www.xyz.com/bme/cbsinterface/common" 
    xmlns:bus1="http://www.xyz.com/bme/cbsinterface/cbs/businessmgr">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <bus:RemoveAppendantProductRequestMsg>
            <RequestHeader>
                <com:CommandId>RemoveAppendantProduct</com:CommandId>
                <com:Version>xx</com:Version>
                <com:TransactionId/>
                <com:SequenceId>xx</com:SequenceId>
                <com:RequestType>Event</com:RequestType>
                <com:SessionEntity>
                    <com:Name>$xyz_Name</com:Name>
                    <com:Password>$xyz_Password</com:Password>
                    <com:RemoteAddress/>
                </com:SessionEntity>
                <com:SerialNo>$xyz_ser_no</com:SerialNo>
            </RequestHeader>
            <RemoveAppendantProductRequest>
                <bus1:SubscriberNo>$xyzr_sub_id</bus1:SubscriberNo>
                <bus1:Product>
                    <bus1:ProductID>$xyz_id</bus1:ProductID>
                    <bus1:ValidMode>123456</bus1:ValidMode>
                    <bus1:ExpireDate>$xyz_eff_date</bus1:ExpireDate>
                </bus1:Product>
            </RemoveAppendantProductRequest>
        </bus:RemoveAppendantProductRequestMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
SOAPXML;

    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
                    echo 'Constructor error' . $err;
    }
    $result = $client->send($request_xml, $soapaction, ''); // passing soap message via soap php client
```

Pls let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why are you creating the xml yourself? there is probably an issue with either the request_xml or you don't need to enclose it in the full soap envelope, as nusoap probably does this. If you can output the request as sent by nusoap, this would help.

Comment: I slightly updated your example php code placing the `$xml_request` assignment into a heredoc block to make the full xml easier to read. Assuming there were no syntax issues with the original, this should work the same as what you posted and you are welcome to apply the change to your source to confirm.

Comment: I have check with the soapUI and copied the same xml as request_xml. so i think issue is not with that.

Comment: Please add the http request that gets the response.